# calculate new column from mapped values

Tags: r

I have a data.frame `df`

```
df = data.frame(v = c('E', 'B', 'EB', 'RM'))
df$n= 100 / apply(df, 1, nchar)
```

Where `v` represents values `E = 4`, `B = 3`, `R = 2`, and `M = 1`

I want to calculate a column like so:

```
   v   n idx
1  E 100 400
2  B 100 300
3 EB  50 350
4 RM  50 150
```

Where idx is `n (v)`. For example for the first row `4 * 100 = 400` and for the last row `(2 + 1) * 50 = 150`

I have something like this:

```
df$e = ifelse(grepl('E', df$v), 4, 0)
df$b = ifelse(grepl('B', df$v), 3, 0)
df$r = ifelse(grepl('R', df$v), 2, 0)
df$m = ifelse(grepl('M', df$v), 1, 0)

df$idx = df$n * (df$e + df$b + df$r + df$m)
```

But it becomes unfeasible as the number of columns grows.

Comment: ps. if anyone can help improve the title, much appreciated. I didn't know quite how to phrase this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** Define a lookup table, `lookup`, and a function `Sum` that takes a vector of single letters, looks up each and sums their lookup number.

split `v` into a list of vectors of single letters and `sapply` over that list using `Sum` mulitplying the result by `n`.

```
lookup <- c(E = 4, B = 3, R = 2, M = 1)
Sum <- function(x) sum(lookup[x])
transform(df, idx = n * sapply(strsplit(as.character(v), ""), Sum))
```

giving:

```
   v   n idx
1  E 100 400
2  B 100 300
3 EB  50 350
4 RM  50 150
```

**2)** An alternative using `lookup` from above is the following which for each character in `v` applies `lookup` using the anonymous function expressed in formula notation creating a list over which we `sapply` the `sum` and finally multiply by `n`.

```
library(gsubfn)
transform(df, idx = n * sapply(strapply(as.character(v), ".", x ~ lookup[x]), sum))
```

**3)** A dplyr/tidyr solution using `lookup` from above is the following.  We insert an `id` to uniquely identify each row and the use `separate_rows` to place each letter of `v` in a separate row.  We then summarize all rows with the same id by looking up each letter and summing.  Finally we remove `id`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
   mutate(id = 1:n()) %>% 
   separate_rows(v, sep = "(?<=.)(?=.)") %>%
   group_by(id, n) %>%
   summarize(idx = sum(n * lookup[v])) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-id)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
     id     n   idx
  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1  100.  400.
2     2  100.  300.
3     3   50.  350.
4     4   50.  150.
```

One could avoid the complex regular expression by replacing the `separate_rows` statement with these two statements:

```
mutate(v = strsplit(as.character(v), "")) %>%
unnest %>%
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a look-up table with your values. Then `match` between a split version (via `strsplit`) of your `df$v` column, `sum` the corresponding values and do your multiplication calculation:

```
lkup <- data.frame(id=c("E","B","R","M"),value=c(4,3,2,1))
sapply(
  strsplit(as.character(df$v),""),
  function(x) sum(lkup$value[match(x,lkup$id)])
) * df$n
#[1] 400 300 350 150
```